# partial derivatives of mutual information

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, information-theory

I am trying to solve this problem:

We have three random variables: $X,Y, Z =f(X)$
I want to calculate $\frac{\partial I(Z;Y)}{\partial p(z_0|x_0)}$
In particular, since $p(z)=\sum_x p(z|x)p(x)$ i could re-write $I(Z;Y)=\sum_{z,y} p(y|x)(\sum_x p(z|x)p(x)) \log{\frac{p(y|z)}{p(y)}}$ erasing the dependence from $p(z)$ inside the logarithm, but is it correct? Is there still a dependence due to $p(y|z)$? 
In the end I came up with something like $\sum_{z,y}p(y|z)p(x_0)\log{\frac{p(y|z)}{p(y)}}$ that doesn't seem to be very interesting, is it?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: If $Z = f(X)$ for a deterministic $f,$ then $p(z_0|x_0) \in \{0,1\}$, in which case the partial derivative w.r.t. it is ill defined. In general, if $Z-X-Y$ form a markov chain, then $p(y|z) = \sum_x p(x,y|z) = \sum_x p(y|x)p(x|z),$ and the final value $p(x|z) = p(z|x) p(x)/p(z)$ depends on the various $p(z|x)$s.